# $f$ non-negative measurable function and $B \subseteq A$ both measurable $ \implies \int_{B} f \leq \int_{A} f $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let us define $$ \int\limits_E f \, dm = \sup Y( E, f ) $$ where $Y(E,f) = \left\{ \int\limits_E \varphi \, dm: 0 \leq \varphi \leq f \right\}$ where $\varphi$ is a simple function. So, I'm trying to show that if $f$ is a non-negative measurable function and $B \subseteq A$ are both measurable then $\int_{B} f \, dm  \leq \int_{A} f \, dm $.

My attempt is to show $ Y(B, f) \subseteq Y(A, f)$. From this we get the desired result since $X \subseteq Y \implies \sup Y \geq \sup X$. So let us pick $x \in Y(B, f) $.
Hence we have $$x = \int\limits_B \varphi \, dm$$ for some simple $\varphi \leq f $. Im stuck here. Can someone help me? Is this the right approach? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a good approach.  Let $\psi$ be defined on $A$ such that $\psi|_B=\varphi$ and $\psi_{A\setminus B}=0$.  Then $\psi$ is a simple function such that $0\leq\psi\leq f$ on $A$, so $\int_A\psi dm$ is in $Y(A,f)$, and $\int_A\psi dm = x$.

Comment: thanks for your time Jonas

Comment: You're welcome @Emprendedor.  What is $g$ in your problem?  Accidentally typed, I suppose?  You can edit.

Comment: g is just a gift of the keyborad

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you can take :

1. First prove it for a measurable characteristic function $\chi_F \leq f$
2. Then prove it for a simple function $\varphi \leq f$ by using linearity of the integral
3. Take supremum.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the proof would be a bit (just a bit, really) easier if you had choose a better notation. Just notice that
$$
  \int_B \varphi
  \leq
  \int_A \varphi
  \leq
  \sup Y(A,f).
$$
Now, take the supremum over $\int_B \varphi$. That is, the supermum over $Y(B,f)$.

With a better notation, you could have taken the supremum over $\varphi$.